# Antimatter: weak and strong forces

Tags: antimatter, weak-interaction, strong-force

Antimatter is known to have equal mass to matter and opposite charge sign. Positron has the same mass as electron and opposite sign of charge, anti-proton has the same mass as proton and opposite sign of charge.

However, in other interactions is matter and antimatter equal? In weak and strong interactions.

Comment: I am not an expert, but as far as I know antimatter has all charges inverted, be it electrical, color, etc. So antimatter has also "negative" color charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anti-particle is a particle with all quantum numbers reversed. This includes electric, weak, and strong charges (if the particle has them), but also others like the lepton number, spin, and more. The only particle properties that are not reversed are energy and momentum. So when a particle and anti-particle meet and anniholate, all quantum numbers zero out, but the total energy and momentum conserve (as two parts of the 4-momentum). This way all conservation laws are obeyed. While charges and quantum numbers can be positive or negative, energy is always positive for both a particle and its anti-particle.